# Attribute Error when attempting to get a value for the field on serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Trying to get the validated_data of each field in serializer and getting same attribute error for 'matrix' and 'operation' field.

error message:AttributeError at /matrix/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `matrix` on serializer `MatrixOperationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `MatrixOperationView` instance.
Original exception text was: 'MatrixOperationView' object has no attribute 'matrix'.

[serializer.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z47xe.jpg)
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCKua.jpg)

these two fields are showing same error even if the Field names are changed from ListField and ChoiceField to Charfield.But I never got this error for CharFields before.could anyone help to figure out the error?

Comment: You should understand what you get in serializer. Use a debugger or just print serializer.validated_data and look.